# Nativescript SideDrawer not able to run in iOS emulator but working fine in android

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Hit the below when running in iOS emulator but working fine in andriod.

JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TKSideDrawerDelegate

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should show some relative code if you want someone to help you

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution as originally posted [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/issues/141#issuecomment-265055393)

> I spent quite some time and finally get it work by using the following
>   steps (in my project folder):
>
> - `tns platform remove ios`
> - `rm -rf node_modules lib platforms`
> - `tns plugin add nativescript-telerik-ui`
> - Modify app.module.ts and add the nativescript-telerik-ui directives respectively
> - **In iOS emulator, delete the existing app (I found this is critical)**
> - `tns run ios --emulator`
>
> I found the critical step seems to first delete the app manually on
>   iOS emulator after the plugin was added.